# OpenStack K8s : start instance for a specific cronjob

Tags: kubernetes, cron, workflow, openstack, openstack-nova

I want to schedule each day a cronjob who create an instance and run a Dockerfile on it.

I created a Mistral Workflow who create an instance with Nova but I don't found how to start a process on the created instance.

Maybe an interaction is possible directly in K8s ?

Thanks!

Comment: I have never used Mistral, but you can launch an instance with a cloudinit or shell script that can do practically anything. This is called [user-data](https://docs.openstack.org/nova/latest/user/metadata.html#user-data) in Nova terminology. Heat has [great support](https://docs.openstack.org/heat/pike/template_guide/software_deployment.html) for it as well. Not sure what this has to do with Kubernetes, though.

Comment: Thank you @berndbausch. I watched on my side Heat and user-data, it seams to work in Heat templates but how we can cron trigger it ? I found https://docs.openstack.org/heat/pike/template_guide/openstack.html#OS::Mistral::CronTrigger but they want a Mistral workflow which didn't accept user-data parameter in nova.servers_create.
Do you know how to cron trigger a Heat task ? thank you !

Comment: You can use cron to launch a stack or an instance, or to update a stack. The question says "a cronjob who create an instance and run a Dockerfile on it". You could put `openstack server create ... --user-data run-docker.sh ...` in your crontab, where *run-docker.sh* is a shell script that runs your Dockerfile.

Comment: @berndbausch I understand :). But in my case I have a K8s infrastructure with 2 instances always started, so if I understand your solution, I need to access one instance to create a manual crontab and that's not possible by using Mistral Workflow, Heat templates or whatever ?
Note I use a managed Kubernetes service

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your precise requirements. Using a user-data script, you can of course create crontabs as well, but I feel I would need to know more about your setup.

Comment: I will explain from A to Z, sorry if I wasn’t clear before ! I want, everyday at 4:00 AM (a cron basically), create a specific instance, launch a script on it and when this script is terminated I want to destroy the instance. I need that because my script needs many RAM and I’m billed hourly. But I don’t want to turn on an instance just only for run a crontab, that’s why I search a solution with Mistral, Heat or whatever on OpenStack because that’s offered by my host. Thank you :)

Comment: Then my first comment is valid. Use a crontab like `0 4 * * * openstack server create ... --user-data myscript.sh ...`. Heat can't be made to schedule something at a certain time. [Mistral can](https://docs.openstack.org/mistral/rocky/overview.html#task-scheduling-cloud-cron), but I don't know how.

Comment: https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Mistral/Cookbooks/AdministrationCloudCron is an example of how to run a command on a list of hosts. Since your list is a single host, you have to simplify the example. However, Mistral seems to be a tool for running workloads on existing hosts and a bit overkill for your purposes. What's wrong with cron? After all, Mistral uses cron for periodic tasks anyway.

Comment: Yes I think you're true. I wanted to know the best way to do, and your solution seems to be the best! Thank you very much :)!

Comment: @berndbausch could you possibly post your comments as answer?

Comment: I hope my answer is complete enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Mistral/Cookbooks/AdministrationCloudCron is an example of how to run a command on a list of hosts, using Mistral. Since your list is a single host, you have to simplify the example. However, Mistral seems to be a tool for running workloads on existing hosts. You, on the other hand, want to run a Dockerfile on a server that you are launching.

My thinking is that Mistral is overkill for your use case. What's wrong with cron? After all, Mistral uses cron for periodic tasks anyway. Use a crontab like `0 4 * * * openstack server create ... --user-data myscript.sh ...`.